# Examine HTTP status code in web browser

Tags: http, browser

I want to verify that my custom-made error pages return the correct [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

- 200 OK
- 301 Moved Permanently
- 401 Unauthorized
- 404 Not Found
- 500 Internal Server Error

etc.

How do I make my web browser show me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the HTTP tool [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

It'll show you the HTTP status code for every request.

Comment: I hope it helps. Another decent HTTP tool is IEWatch, but it's not free. I find Fiddler is suffice.

Comment: I was looking through old posts and ran across this one. I no longer  use fiddler as this is built into the dev tools in IE and FF (press F12)

Answer (score 1):

Use [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) Add-on for Mozilla firefox.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://chathuranga.chandrasekara.googlepages.com/Livehttp.PNG))</sub>